# What is the basic use of calling the private function inside the public function?

Tags: javascript

What is the perpose of calling privateMethod from the publicMethod?
Can't we just define the content of privateMethod inside the public method and do the same thing ?

```
var basketModule =  (function() {

      var basket = [];

  function privateMethod() {
      console.log(basket);
  }

  return {
      publicMethod: function(){
              privateMethod();
      }
  };

})());
basketModule.publicMethod();
```

Comment: If you define it inside the public method then you are recreating the private method every time.

Comment: The example you have is contrived. If you were to write something exactly like that then yes, there'd be no reason to have a private function. But usually you have private functions for performing other kinds of work that the outside world shouldn't care about.

Comment: When you want to do some property updation tasks may be;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your simple example, there is not really a reason for `privateMethod` to exist because all `publicMethod` does is call it, but in a more real-world example, the private methods would do things that you don't want other modules calling on their own.

For example, this is a snippet of code that I worked on today, reduced to make it a good example:

```
(function(){

  function _renderTreeLevel() { ... }

  function _backfillAllSelectedStates() { ... }

  function _updateSelectedCount() { ... }

  return {
    render: function() {
      var expandCollapse = new ExpandCollapse();
      expandCollapse.render();

      _renderTreeLevel(0, this.ui.treeRegion, this.treeData);
      _backfillAllSelectedStates();
      _updateSelectedCount((this.options.selected || []).length);

      $('.collapse').collapse();
    }
 };

})();
```

The 3 "private" function that start with '`_`' are just functions that I put code into for refactoring and making the code cleaner and more reusable. They are not functions that I want someone to be able to call.

Users of this module should call `render()` only.

The reasoning is the same as any other language that has public and private members built-in, like C# or Java, but since JavaScript doesn't provide that concept, this is the pattern that people follow to provide a similar behavior.